# Sqlalchemy with_for_update not locking the same row within the second session

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Having the following code:

```
def create_session(engine):
    return session(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

def test_row_was_locked(engine, create_table_data):
    session_1 = create_session(engine)
    product_set_query_from_1st_query = (
        session_1.query(ProductSet)
        .filter(ProductSet.id ==PRODUCT_SET_ID_1)
        .with_for_update(of=ProductSet)
        .one()
    )
    product_set_query_from_1st_query.filters = [{"size": 5, "condition": "EQUALS"}]

    session_2 = create_session(engine)
    product_set_from_2nd_query = (
        session_2.query(ProductSet)
        .filter(ProductSet.id == PRODUCT_SET_ID_1)
        .with_for_update(of=ProductSet)
        .one()
    )
    product_set_from_2nd_query.condition = Condition.OR
    
    session_2.commit()
    session_1.commit()
```

It turns out, that updates were successful, no errors raised. I want a one row to be locked, until changes on it were committed, however with different sessions, imitating two calls, where updates from one should be committed prior to updates from another. DB is in default state, just installed from brew repository, nothing special there.